# iOS - How extracting and store data using jSON and objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm developing an application that uses JSON to save notes.

Specifically, I have a UITableView and a button 'add'.
Every time I press 'add' step to another view controller which has 3 textfield and a button 'save'. Every time I press on save I would like to save the contents of the textfield 3 a JSON file locally (so for example if I create 10 notes, I have 10 JSON files).

I searched online material, guides but I found nothing for my purpose, I would be very glad if you could help me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of JSON saving to file in Objective-C:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableDictionary *json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
json[@"version"] = @(1);
json[@"content"] = myTextField.text;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog("Error %@ converting dictionary %@ to JSON", error, json);
} else {
    [jsonData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a dictionary with you JSON content

```
let json: [String:Any] = [
    "key1": "Hello World!",
    "key2": 1.0
]
```

Then use [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization) to convert it to a Data object and write this object to disk

```
do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file")
    try data.write(to: url, options: [])
}
catch {
    print("An error occured : \(error)")
}
```